# Что возвращает строка Integer.valueOf(...)?

Tags: android, java

Не уверен, что получится без остального исходного кода, но получается слишком много кода.
Вопрос: что возвращает эта строчка:

```
res = Integer.valueOf(results.getAttributes().getNamedItem("count").getNodeValue());
```

И что за "count"? Это атрибут какой-то? Или блок в xml, который парсится?

```
public static int numResults(Document doc){     
        Node results = doc.getDocumentElement();
        int res = -1;

        try{
            res = Integer.valueOf(results.getAttributes().getNamedItem("count").getNodeValue());
        }catch(Exception e ){
            res = -1;
        }

        return res;
    }
```

Это потом проверяется в активити

```
 if((numResults <= 0)){
        Toast.makeText(Main.this, "Geen resultaten gevonden", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
        finish();
    }
```

И больше - ни слово про эту функцию...Вот я и ломаю голову...Уже второй день пытаюсь парсинг скопипастить...Знания java не хватает к написанию самостоятельно...

Comment: У меня потом проходит проверка, не res <=0 - ексепшн...

Comment: А к какому классу принадлежит results никак нельзя что ли?

Comment: Node results = doc.getDocumentElement();
эта строчка по ходу?

Comment: Дальше смотрите, что передается в метод numResults.
А так сам метод понятен - он пытается прочитать значение атрибута count. Если не получается - возвращает -1. Так как кол-во чего то обычно 0 и больше, то код дальше проверяет на это условие и ругается, если что.

Если я правильно понимаю код, то в doc должно прийти что то вида `<noda count="10".. />`

Comment: Вы правы - <results count="6"> получается он пытается достать 6?
Понял...Буду разбираться, почему не доходит до него...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Integer.valueOf - это преобразовать аргумент (который в данном случае - целое или строка) в целое.
В данном случае аргумент с большой вероятностью - строка.
Конструкция `results.getAttributes().getNamedItem("count").getNodeValue())` - это действительно похоже на парсинг xml.

Comment: Уже лучше...Только как проследить...Какую именно строку он превращает в инт? И что это может значить...? И что за параметр count?
Если надо больше исходника - выложу здесь.

Comment: А это легко. Добавьте перед этой строкой такую

    Log.d("TAG", results.getAttributes().getNamedItem("count").getNodeValue());

И потом в логе смотрите (например с помощью ddms).
А кода можно побольше, что бы было понятно, откуда оно его читает, какие типы переменных...

Comment: Выложил в тексте вопроса, извиняюсь, что сразу попросил включить экстрасенса)

Comment: Может у вас есть скайп и есть время на ещё пару вопросов? Не могу разобраться в парсинге, как и говорил выше, не хватает знаний...